# CNN producing same value for every pixel of an image and for every input image after showing low loss value

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am training a convolutional neural network with time series data in grid form as an input and time series data as an output as well. While training the loss is very low, and when I look at the outputs produced during training it is quite good, very similar to the target. But once the training finishes and I pass an input from training data, it gives weird result with same value as output for every pixel. Even for the different image it is same exact value, i.e the output produces only one value and fills every box with it.

While training:

```
Input: tensor([0.4227, 0.4396, 0.4807, 0.5201, 0.5685, 0.6009, 0.5774, 0.5286, 0.4780,
        0.4228, 0.3570, 0.3578, 0.3667, 0.4322, 0.5659, 0.6624, 0.7082, 0.7285,
        0.6903, 0.6409, 0.6031, 0.4915, 0.3842, 0.3293, 0.3065, 0.3234, 0.4052,
        0.5047, 0.5763, 0.6334, 0.6080, 0.5724, 0.5240, 0.4635, 0.4294, 0.3948,
        0.4014, 0.4336, 0.5007, 0.5419, 0.5733, 0.5877, 0.5483, 0.5295, 0.4945,
        0.5066, 0.5381, 0.5620, 0.5508, 0.5609, 0.5571, 0.5736, 0.5208, 0.4679,
        0.3421, 0.2895, 0.2682, 0.3878, 0.4691, 0.5377, 0.5905, 0.5975, 0.6014,
        0.5705, 0.5285, 0.4112, 0.3662, 0.3606, 0.4075, 0.4676, 0.5179, 0.5378,
        0.5755, 0.5833, 0.5459, 0.5206, 0.4838, 0.4425, 0.4292, 0.4087, 0.4459,
        0.5064, 0.5535, 0.5751, 0.5140, 0.4675, 0.3972, 0.3673, 0.3539, 0.3515,
        0.3994, 0.4857, 0.5820, 0.6970, 0.7130, 0.6680, 0.5708, 0.4864, 0.4359,
        0.4105], device='cuda:0')
Output: tensor([0.4614, 0.4805, 0.5091, 0.5421, 0.5764, 0.5922, 0.5825, 0.5401, 0.4735,
        0.4073, 0.3615, 0.3559, 0.3913, 0.4667, 0.5621, 0.6461, 0.7030, 0.7202,
        0.7061, 0.6570, 0.5732, 0.4780, 0.3900, 0.3353, 0.3184, 0.3438, 0.4079,
        0.4936, 0.5760, 0.6204, 0.6218, 0.5804, 0.5087, 0.4384, 0.3935, 0.3855,
        0.4119, 0.4582, 0.5110, 0.5510, 0.5716, 0.5718, 0.5569, 0.5388, 0.5202,
        0.5140, 0.5222, 0.5411, 0.5680, 0.5872, 0.5868, 0.5599, 0.5009, 0.4232,
        0.3503, 0.3091, 0.3084, 0.3538, 0.4377, 0.5303, 0.6024, 0.6295, 0.6133,
        0.5619, 0.4942, 0.4333, 0.3954, 0.3897, 0.4099, 0.4527, 0.5052, 0.5516,
        0.5841, 0.5913, 0.5733, 0.5360, 0.4865, 0.4438, 0.4207, 0.4274, 0.4616,
        0.5082, 0.5488, 0.5582, 0.5297, 0.4690, 0.3972, 0.3467, 0.3321, 0.3583,
        0.4223, 0.5072, 0.5935, 0.6520, 0.6777, 0.6678, 0.6242, 0.5574, 0.4826,
        0.4245], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SelectBackward0>)
```

After training finishes:

```
Input: tensor([0.4992, 0.4980, 0.5664, 0.5931, 0.6129, 0.6245, 0.6198, 0.5699, 0.4931,
        0.4925, 0.4626, 0.4116, 0.3559, 0.3145, 0.3470, 0.4358, 0.5450, 0.6205,
        0.6392, 0.6169, 0.5601, 0.4736, 0.4324, 0.3986, 0.3871, 0.3342, 0.3693,
        0.4783, 0.5535, 0.6388, 0.6912, 0.6931, 0.6628, 0.6182, 0.5680, 0.5506,
        0.5266, 0.4951, 0.4773, 0.5055, 0.4809, 0.4301, 0.4123, 0.4608, 0.4991,
        0.5286, 0.5015, 0.4570, 0.4586, 0.5149, 0.5658, 0.6096, 0.5619, 0.5430,
        0.4721, 0.4153, 0.4204, 0.4200, 0.4546, 0.5500, 0.6355, 0.7143, 0.7294,
        0.7051, 0.6539, 0.5768, 0.4502, 0.3775, 0.3197, 0.3129, 0.3145, 0.3578,
        0.4287, 0.5072, 0.5717, 0.5766, 0.5901, 0.5387, 0.4811, 0.3947, 0.3430,
        0.3755, 0.4364, 0.5128, 0.5465, 0.5489, 0.5900, 0.6103, 0.6149, 0.6073,
        0.5876, 0.5211, 0.4783, 0.4792, 0.4736, 0.4787, 0.4713, 0.4335, 0.3832,
        0.3183])

Output: tensor([0.5465, 0.5463, 0.5463, 0.5464, 0.5465, 0.5463, 0.5463, 0.5462, 0.5460,
        0.5463, 0.5464, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5461, 0.5459, 0.5463, 0.5465, 0.5462,
        0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5460, 0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459,
        0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459, 0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462,
        0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459, 0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459,
        0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459, 0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462,
        0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459, 0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459,
        0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459, 0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462,
        0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459, 0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5461, 0.5459,
        0.5462, 0.5466, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5462, 0.5459, 0.5462, 0.5465, 0.5462,
        0.5461, 0.5461, 0.5459, 0.5461, 0.5465, 0.5462, 0.5461, 0.5461, 0.5460,
        0.5461], device='cuda:0')
```

What causes this to happen, I'm very confused!?